# ParticlesJS un-clickable areas, wrong context box

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, particles.js

I'm building a site that I've hosted here:

**http://whendoesitair.info/**

I'm running into two issues on the landing page.

**1.)** The right click context menus are non-standard when you right-click outside of a div. E.x: [image: H]

Here is an example of the correct behavior I'm trying to make happen anywhere you right-click:

[image]

**2.)** The other (minor) problem, is that the particles will have no effects when you left click directly to the right or left of a div. For example, to the right or left of the header tag, or the searchbox.

Here is how I load-in the particles, in my:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WhenDoesItAir</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body style="display: block; height: 0vh; z-index: 5;">
  <app-root></app-root>
    <div id="particles-js" style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -5;">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is how I load particles in my my Landing Page, in my

**Landingpage.component.ts**

```
  declare var particlesJS: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // particles
     particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', null);
  }
```

How can I give the correct context-menus when a user right clicks? Or how can I fix the particle behavior when it's overlapping a div?